# validating xml against xml schema definitions (XSD)

Tags: node.js, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I have read contents from an HTML form and made a var xml using the xmlbuilder module, builder.create().

I have a nodejs app called app.js in the same folder (basically everything in my question is in one folder)

The purpose of my app is to validate my newly created var xml against a schema located in the same directory as of my nodejs app.js

```
var validator = require('xsd-schema-validator');
.
.
. 
.
validator.validateXML(xml,'mobilephone.xsd', function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
              .
              .
              .
      }
 });
```

however it gives me the following error: Error: invalid xml (status=WITH_ERRORS)

before validation i have used console.log(xml) command to print the xml var and it looks like a perfect xml document with the header < ?xml version="1.0"?>

I went a step further and created a separate xml file and copied and pasted the contents of var xml and it validates against the xsd without any errors.

So what could possible be wrong?

My doubts are:

1. Is my syntax:

   ```
   validator.validateXML(xml,'mobilephone.xsd', function(err, result)
   ```

correct?

If its correct what else is the issue?